# Powershell DBCC CheckDB from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2005

I was wondering if anyone could help with the following code shown. I'm basically trying to get this code re-hashed if possible to allow me to run it against a set of server names supplied in a text file named "servers.txt".

The DBCC should be run by the PS script and run against all DB for that servername. I'm not up to speed enough with PS to understand how to do this for this script.

How to change it allow to plug in values instead of being hardcoded for each servername?

I've read a bit around this and looked at the `Invoke-Sql` command which I believe is a SQL 2008 extension to PS.

Unfortunately the PS environment is from a SQL 2005 box and I dont have the power to get this moved so dont think ill be able to use invoke

Please see the original code and then my experiment to try and get it to run using invoke.

```
$ScriptName = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Name
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.SqlClient")
$ConnString = "Server=DB-OCC05;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=master;Application Name=$ScriptName"
$MasterConn = new-object ('System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection') $ConnString
$MasterCmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$MasterCmd.Connection = $MasterConn
$SqlDBCC = "DBCC CHECKDB(master) WITH TABLERESULTS"
$MasterCmd.CommandText = $SqlDBCC
$MasterConn.Open()
$Rset = $MasterCmd.ExecuteReader()
If ($Rset.HasRows -eq $true) {
    While ($Rset.Read()) {
        $line = $Rset["MessageText"]
        If ($Rset["Level"] -gt 10) {
            Write-Host $line -backgroundcolor Yellow -foregroundcolor Red
        } else {
            Write-Host $line 
        }
    }
    $Rset.Close()
}
$MasterConn.Close()
```

And then my test running from SQL 2005 environment:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"
```

And also tried this test:

```
gc "C:\Powershell\Servers.txt" | foreach-object {Invoke-Sqlcmd "DBCC checkdb;" -ServerInstance "$_\MyInstance"}
```

But the above test runs didnt work cause of the:

> The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few modifications to your script. Everything is basically the same except for the connection string and the few lines at the bottom for loading your servers.txt file (a text file with one line per instance) and enumerating its content:

```
function Execute-DBCC
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$serverInstance
    )

    $connString = "Server=$serverInstance;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=master;Application Name=$ScriptName"
    $masterConn = new-object ('System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection') $connString
    $masterCmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
    $masterCmd.Connection = $masterConn

    $masterCmd.CommandText = "EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'DBCC CHECKDB([?]) WITH TABLERESULTS'"
    $masterConn.Open()
    $reader = $masterCmd.ExecuteReader()

    if ($reader.HasRows -eq $true) 
    {
        while ($reader.Read()) 
        {
            $messageText = $reader["MessageText"]

            if ($reader["Level"] -gt 10) 
                { Write-Host $messageText -backgroundcolor Yellow -foregroundcolor Red  } 
            else 
                { Write-Host $messageText  }
        }

        $reader.Close()
    }

    $masterConn.Close() 
}




[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.SqlClient")

$servers = @(Get-Content ".\servers.txt")

$servers | %{
    Execute-DBCC $_
}
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you - it works really well.. I cant ask for more but I am ! Sorry! Could you help show me how to export the results to an csv file for example .. I see there is the command Export-Csv "c:\powershell\reports\DBCC_results.csv" for example..

Comment: something like this ?                                         {Export-Csv "c:\powershell\DBCC\$messageText-DBCC.csv"}

Comment: Have tested the script with one server name only in txt file and getting the same error even trying different servers - 2008 and 2005.............it seems to manage master DB and then following.......................Exception calling "Close" with "0" argument(s): "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not re sponding." At C:\Powershell\CheckDB.ps1:27 char:22 + $reader.Close <<<< () + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException